# How to split string variable by multiple characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I need to split string variable by multiple characters, in my case by `"   "`;
Here is my code:

```
string s_var = "New   String   variable";
string[] s_mas = s_var.Split("   ");
```

The Split() method isn't working for me, it says that the argument `"   "` is invalid.
Hoping you guys know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not specifying the correct arguments.

- If you want to split by a string, you need to specify an array.
- You also need to specify whether or not to discard empty strings.

Try this:

```
var s_mas = s_var.Split(new[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: [string.Split @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've always wondered how this works `new[]` ? does it know that it is array of strings ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir you can infer type of array by looking at its arguments. So in this case we know `new[]` is same as `new string[]` because we've used `string` argument.

Comment: @RoyiNamir take a look at [Implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)